# Reset css required for bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `UL` many places in my website. By default, bullets are displaying in all places. I don't want to have bullet points rather than apply `list-style:none` to `UL`. What should i do?

Is any reset css required for bootstrap? 
Shall i write `custom css` for `UL{list-style:none}`? or need to add any reset css?

Comment: Yes you are right, use custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use custom CSS

Bootstrap by default applies a `list-style` to `ul` elements so if you don't want that, either remove that code from their core CSS file or override it.

Comment: *either remove that code from their core CSS file* No, please don't advise to do that. Always override, don't touch the core CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to apply the customized style to any page is to make the custom css file which can be link to any page for giving styles.
Ideally dont modify any of the predefined bootstrap file it may cause ur code to break at some point or changing the style in entire website.
So it is advisable to make a custom css file.